# Enforcing Nested Uniquess in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have three MS SQL Server (2008) tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[blog_BlogSet]
(
    [BlogSetId]         NVARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.blog_BlogSet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BlogSetId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[blog_Persona]
(
    [PersonaId]         INT                 IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BlogSetId]         NVARCHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
    [Name]              NVARCHAR(128)       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_blog_Persona] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PersonaId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_blog_Persona_blog_BlogSet] FOREIGN KEY ([BlogSetId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[blog_BlogSet] ([BlogSetId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_blog_Persona_Name]
    ON [dbo].[blog_Persona]([BlogSetId] ASC, [Name] ASC);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[blog_Blog]
(
    [BlogId]            INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonaId]         INT             NOT NULL,
    [Title]             NVARCHAR (128)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_blog_BlogId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BlogId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_blog_Blog_blog_Persona] FOREIGN KEY ([PersonaId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[blog_Persona] ([PersonaId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

So, a BlogSet contains multiple BlogPersonas and each BlogPersona can contain multiple Blogs.  Each BlogPersona.Name is unique within the BlogSet.

I would now like to make the Blog.Title field unique within the BlogSet.  I can see how I would do this within the BlogPersona, but I am note sure how to do this 'up the table hierarchy'.   Things I have considered are:

1. Create a BEFORE INSERT/BEFORE UPDATE trigger
2. Restructure the tables so that both BlogPersona *and* Blog both reference a BlogSetId foreign key (this just seems wrong as I then have to worry about synchronising the Blog.BlogSetId against the assigned Blog.Persona.BlogSetId).

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: For 2, you don't have to worry about synchronization if you create a super-key in `BlogPersona` across both the `PersonaId` *and* the `BlogSetId` columns, and then use that - either as a replacement, or in additional - in a foreign key reference.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you tell me how I would go about creating a 'super-key' when the PersonaId is an automatically populated INT identity column? In other words, when I INSERT a new BlogPersona record, how would I define the 'super-key' column?

Comment: Why not just move the title to the `blog_Persona` table and add a unique index on `BlogSetId` and `title`?

Comment: Hi Zohar, BlogPersonas my own multiple Blogs, but I think your idea has made me think about creating a View of the three tables and then generating a unique index on the view's BlogSetId and Blog.Title